# Will I still have a geo-tag if I take a screenshot on my computer?

Tags: iphone, mac, geolocation

I am sure the answer is no but I am always a bit more investigative.

Let's say I took an picture with my iPhone 5 and the image has geo tags.  I email it to myself and then I take a screenshot my using the Preview tool.  Will I still have geo-tag information on that image or since I took a snapshot only on my Mac, it won't have it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about taking a screenshot on your Mac of the iPhone image, in which case, no, it won't have any geo-tagging information embedded.

However if you want to remove geo-tags from any photos (screenshots included) that you do have, the more convenient way is probably to use a tool like [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) to strip out the EXIF data (which is the metadata containing geolocation data, amongst other things). That way you preserve the quality of the original, and you don't need to bother exactly trimming the size of the screenshot you take to the photo.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Preview.app can show you if a GPS tag is present or not.

In Preview.app, open the inspector window (using Tools > Show Inspector) and select the "More Info" tab (with the "i" icon).  If you see a GPS tab (within the More Info tab), along with General, Exif and so on, then the image has a GPS tag.

I'm not absolutely sure that this feature of Preview is a reliable way of determining the absence of a GPS tag.  So: an alternative I've also used is [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).  This is a command line tool which can also show any GPS tags present in an image.